# ValidateInput(true) not working accepting html tags with ajax post call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to block HTML tags. I'm passing HTML tags to action and it is accepting it. I have used [ValidateInput(true)] but still its accepting HTML. By default, validation is enabled but in this case, it is not working

Im using ajax call to send data :

```
$.ajax({
    method: "Post",
    url: "/Home/MyAction",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ htm: "<span>abc</span>"}),
    success: function (d) {
        UnBlockUI();
        if ($.type(d) == "string")
            AccessDenied();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        UnBlockUI();
        ErrorMessage("Something went wrong, please try again");
    }
});
```

The code:

```
[ValidateInput(true)] 
public ActionResult MyAction(string htm) 
{ 
    return View(htm); 
}
```

any solution to get rid of this problem

Thanks :)

Comment: could you add the code?

Comment: [ValidateInput(true)] public ActionResult MyAction(string htm)
        { 
            return View(htm);
        }

Comment: Why are you trying to annotate with [ValidateInput(true)], if it's validating by default? The only reason you would use the attribute, is if you want to disable validation for the action with [ValidateInput(false)]

Comment: You possibly have `requestValidationMode="2.0"` in the config?

Comment: @MichaelCleverly it's not validating by default in this case

Comment: is it being escaped before being passed to the action?

Comment: @GSerg requestValidationMode="2.0" i have checked it with and without it already

Comment: @Orangesandlemons it dives into the action with html

Comment: do you have the action twice?

Comment: It should have been `requestValidationMode="4.5"` @Mike.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons no

Comment: You should give some more details about your page and post method and possibly override filters, attributes and web configuration.

Comment: @Stefan I have override the Authorize attribute but its not on action

Comment: Ah, yes, but the thing is; your question in it's current state does not provide much detail about your issue and is therefore unlikely to get many helpful answers. Also, please include additional information, such as the `requestValidationMode` in your original question. This is not to be a jerk but to help you get your answer faster ;-) Readers can spot the issue easier and therefore will be more likely to post helpful answers.

Comment: @Stefan i have updated the post please see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSS validation from MVC action from JSON ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846577/xss-validation-from-mvc-action-from-json-ajax-post)

Answer (score 2):

@Biby Augustine is right....

Simply pass the Object and it validates donot do JSON.stringify() as it converts the object to valid json (string) which is not validated by ValidateInput annotation

```
 $.ajax({
    method: "Post",
    url: "/Home/MyAction", 
    data: dataObject,
    success: function (d) {
        UnBlockUI(); 
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        UnBlockUI();
        ErrorMessage("Something went wrong, please try again");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ValidateInput validates if there any suspicious requests coming on Form submission.

Form submission means do post back of the entire form by click on a submit button.

For example

HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="frmDemo" method="post" action="/Home/Demo">
<input type="hidden" id="hdnText" value="<span>Testing</span>"/>

<button type="submit" form="frmDemo" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

In ActionResult

```
[HttpPost,ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Demo(FormCollection frm)
{
   frm["hdnText"].ToString(); //this will give you the result
}
```

In case any html tag encountered while posting it will be blocked.

Comment: it is validating same tag when I pass it in querystring and hit enter but not validating when gone through AJAX POST call

Comment: Setting ValidateInput to false will allow "potentially dangerous requests" in the Request.Form. I think there is not happening any form submission in ajax call. But while you are submitting using query string it is happening, that is why the error occurred. One way you need to block this, submit the form and read values in HttpPost, then ValidateInput will work. I think you got an idea.

Comment: can you give a example of it what you are saying .. thanks , but i think its not working in post call form submission

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check it.